# SQL Server and ASP.NET MVC performance Issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm profiling a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure and if it was executed from my ASP.NET MVC 4 app, it delays for 4 seconds, but if I manually execute the same stored proceedure with the same parameters from SQL Server Management Studio it only delays for 250 milliseconds and it makes 1% reads comparing to the first one.

Any idea why this can happen and how I can solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you executing it with the same inputs at the code does?

Comment: yes, same input, I copy profiler text and paste into management studio  and I get no delays

Comment: Why negative votes, how much info do you need?

Comment: Here's an article that may help.  It's kinda long, but worth the time.  http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: excelent thank you DMason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it a fair test ensure you clear your SQL Server buffers before you run the query from management studio. SQL Server caches result sets. They should be equal? If so you need to do some query tuning. Post the execution plan here and I will attempt to diagnose the issue.

```
CHECKPOINT; 
GO 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS; 
GO
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
GO
```

Comment: Its works like a charm! But, I really don't understand why the cache or plan could be diferent with same query and parameters from diferents enviroments. Thank you for your help

Comment: SQL Server decides how best to retrieve data from your table based on a whole bunch of factors. Essentially it learns from the past (+  indexes, useage statistics etc etc) that you have defined. By running those statements you are effectively telling it to start from scratch and relearn how best to call your procedures again. Before you deal with any SQL performance issues, best to clear down the cache and then look into the performance issues otherwise you could be spending a whole bunch of time trying to diagnose an issue that a clever guy from Microsoft has already solved for you. Enjoy.